# Android Socket Connectio Refused

Tags: android, sockets, port

I am having trouble connecting two android phones via socket i am using android debug bridge to connect the phones to my PC from which i can launch the emulator on the phones.

I launch the server on one phone and try to connect with the other however i get the following error on my client side:

```
 W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 8080): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED
```

Server

```
private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
    static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
        Log.d("Quiz", "Server creation connection success");
        Log.d("Quiz", "Server local port "+serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        Log.d("Quiz", "Server local port "+serverSocket.getInetAddress());

        HostingScreen.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        });

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            count++;
            message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
                    + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n";

            HostingScreen.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    msg.setText(message);
                }
            });

            SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = new SocketServerReplyThread(
                    socket, count);
            socketServerReplyThread.run();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client

```
 @Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(host,port);
        Log.d("Quiz", "Client socket success");
        connected = true;
        while (connected) {
            try {
                Log.d("Quiz", "Sending command");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                        .getOutputStream())), true);
                // where you issue the commands
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(socket != null){
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The port is hard coded to port 8080 for both the server and the client for the time being, the host address is found when i make a connection between the phones by using the following code:

Connection

```
        private void onConnectionChanged(Intent intent) {
        final NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        final WifiP2pInfo p2pInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_INFO);
        isConnected = netInfo.isConnected();
        if (isConnected) {
            //Get host connection info
            wifiMgr.requestConnectionInfo(channel, new ConnectionInfoListener() {

                @Override
                public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {
                    wifiMgr.requestGroupInfo(channel, new GroupInfoListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup group) {
                            if (group == null)
                                return;
                            WiFiP2P.this.group = group;
                            Log.d(TAG, "Wifi p2p connection group is  " + group.getNetworkName());
                            Log.d(TAG, "Group size " + group.getClientList().size());
                            fireOnConnectionSucceed(group.getNetworkName(), group.getPassphrase());
                            //create client if not host
                            if(info.isGroupOwner) {
                                Client client = new Client(8080, p2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
                                client.execute();
                                Log.d(TAG, "Client launch success");
                                Log.d(TAG, "Host address " + p2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (isConnected && !info.isGroupOwner) {
                    } else {
                        startDiscovery();
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            group = null;
            fireOnConnectionLost();
        }
    }
```

I check to see if the person connected is the host or not, if not i launch the client passing the port and host address to the client which is an Aysnc task where the socket to connect is created.

The error occurs in the client when

```
 socket = new Socket(host,port);
```

is used causing the error stated.

Any ideas as to what the problem could be? They both connect to each other over WiFi but when i try to connect to the server socket it fails.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
To clear somethings up, i use the adb to get the app from my computer onto my phone from which i can launch the app.

I am connecting both phones using wifimanager i need to find which of the phones created the wifi group and then that person is the host of the server to which i can connect the problem arises when i try to launch a socket to connect to the host using the host address from the connect info.

Comment: `launch the emulator on the phones`. ???????

Comment: `I check to see if the person connected is the host or not`. Sorry but i have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: `i am using android debug bridge to connect the phones to my PC `. I see no reason to connect them with your pc.

Comment: i need to get the app from my pc and put it on my phone i able to launch the app which is what i need the bridge for, i use wifimanager to connect the two phones i then check which phone is the host of the group.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem, it turns out the device which was hosting the server wasn't being designated the group owner.

```
config.groupOwnerIntent=0;
```

Setting the owner intent of connecting devices to 0 fixed the problem.